# Display alert only once per application launch on android

Tags: android

I want to add a startup alert for my application,but it keeps showing up each time I go back to the main screen.How can I do it? Newbie here and thanks in regard.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("About:");
        String alert1 = "Message here " ;
        String alert2 = "Message here "  ;
        String alert3 = "Message here " ;
        alertDialog.setMessage(alert1 +"\n"+ alert2 +"\n"+ alert3); 
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Where is this code called, onResume()?

Comment: set a boolean variable

Comment: It's write bellow 
public class Main_Screen extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
HERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a boolean variable (initially set to true) to tell you if it is the first run or not and store it in `Preferences`.

```
private boolean isFirstRun = true;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
```

Inside on create(), read that value from `Preferences` in case it exists. The default value is true.

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
isFirstRun = prefs.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
```

Only show your `Dialog` if that variable value is true. 
Once you have shown your `Dialog`, set that variable to false and save it in `Preferences`.

```
if(isFirstRun){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("About:");
        String alert1 = "Message here " ;
        String alert2 = "Message here "  ;
        String alert3 = "Message here " ;
        alertDialog.setMessage(alert1 +"\n"+ alert2 +"\n"+ alert3); 
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
        alert.show();
}

isFirstRun = false;

prefs.edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", isFirstRun).commit();
```

The next times you run your code, the variable will be always false and therefore the `Dialog` won't show.

Edit:

Inside `onStop()`, do:

```
if(alert!=null && alert.isShowing())
   alert.dismiss();
```

This will dismiss the Dialog when you exit the Activity to another one. Once you press back Button, the `Dialog` won't show again.

Comment: Thanks for response.This one works but it prevents the alert from running on a new application launch.Also I had to replace "(context)" with "(getBaseContext())" due to an error.

Comment: My mistake. I have edited the code so context is this

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. If you want it to show in every app launch, forget the Preferences part. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.Is this code supposed to prevent the alert from showing up ever again? Because if close the emulator and relaunch it wont show.I have to uninstall and reinstall to see it again.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood it. Do not use Preferences at all and it will work.

Comment: Do not forget to declare private AlertDialog alert; as a global variable, so you can access it inside onStop().